# single-row sub query returning more than row when creating for a view

Tags: sql

I am working on a view that selects the following information. 
The issue I am having is with the single row subquery is returning more than one row. However, I cannot see for myself what the issue is. Any advice would be helpful

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW eqx_dir_ind_rep_emp_v (person_id,
                                          supervisor_id,
                                          employee_name,
                                          supervisor_name
                                         )
 AS
    SELECT     paf.person_id, paf.supervisor_id,
              (SELECT full_name employee_name
                 FROM per_people_f
                    WHERE person_id = paf.person_id
                      AND SYSDATE BETWEEN effective_start_date AND effective_end_date)
                                                            employee_name,
              (SELECT full_name supervisor_name
                 FROM per_people_f
                    WHERE person_id = supervisor_id
                      AND SYSDATE BETWEEN effective_start_date AND effective_end_date)
                                                          supervisor_name
   FROM apps.per_all_assignments_f paf
```

Comment: add `TOP 1` to your inner/sub queries to make sure only one row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following the inner select statements you have.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW eqx_dir_ind_rep_emp_v (person_id,
                                          supervisor_id,
                                          employee_name,
                                          supervisor_name
                                         )
 AS
    SELECT     paf.person_id, paf.supervisor_id,
              (SELECT full_name employee_name
                 FROM per_people_f
                    WHERE person_id = paf.person_id
                      AND SYSDATE BETWEEN effective_start_date AND effective_end_date
                      AND rownum = 1)
                                                            employee_name,
              (SELECT full_name supervisor_name
                 FROM per_people_f
                    WHERE person_id = supervisor_id
                      AND SYSDATE BETWEEN effective_start_date AND effective_end_date
                      AND rownum = 1)
                                                          supervisor_name
   FROM apps.per_all_assignments_f paf
```